# How to send an email with IBM Message Broker?

Tags: email, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

As a part of overall project, I need to create one Message-Broker application which accepts data in XML format and produce email.

I created one message flow like below

"MQ Input - Compute - emailoutput"

Please help me what should I write in xml file to generate the above flow.

The esql file contain the below code:
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        CALL CopyMessageHeaders();

```
    -- Add recipient information to the EmailOutputHeader
    SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader.To = '<recipient email address>';
    SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader.Cc = '<recipient email address>';
    SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader.Bcc = '<recipient email address>';

    -- Add sender information to EmailOutputHeader
    SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader.From = '<sender email address>';
    SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader."Reply-To" = '<reply email address>';

    -- Add subject to EmailOutputHeader
    SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader.Subject = 'Replaced by ESQL compute node.';

    -- Add SMTP server information to the LocalEnvironment
    SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.Email.SMTPServer ='<smtp.server:port>';

    -- Create a new message body, which will be sent as the main text of the email.
    SET OutputRoot.BLOB.BLOB = CAST('This is the new text for the body of the email.' AS BLOB CCSID 1208);          

    RETURN TRUE; 
END;
```

Comment: Are you trying to programtically generate a flow? In which case the only supported option is to use the Message Flow API?

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea what xml file you're talking about.
Lay out msg flow in the message broker toolkit, by adding and connecting the three nodes you specified. Then add your code to the Compute Node.

Comment: can give one sample email sending using wmb with coding and what are the flow u preferred

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values Using XPATH, by using InputRoot.XMLNC , using Environment or LocalEnvironment.
If we take your requirements , 
that Seems The Message come from your MQInput node you are using XMLNSC Parser.

```
  -- Add recipient information to the EmailOutputHeader
  SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader.To = InputRoot.XMLNSC.EmailData.To;

  -- Add sender information to EmailOutputHeader
  SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader.From = InputRoot.XMLNSC.EmailData.From;

  -- Add subject to EmailOutputHeader
  SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader.Subject = InputRoot.XMLNSC.EmailData.Subject;

  -- Add SMTP server information to the LocalEnvironment
  -- You can Add Smtp Server From Configuration in Your Broker Administration side as Configurable Service
  SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.Email.SMTPServer ='<smtp.server:port>';

  -- Create a new message body, which will be sent as the main text of the email.
  SET OutputRoot.BLOB.BLOB = CAST(InputRoot.EmailData.Body AS BLOB CCSID 1208);
```

For Testing , In Test Client  Type this XML File

```
<EmailData>
    <To>recieverEmail@example.com</To>
    <From>fooSenderEmail@example.com</From>
    <Subject>Testing Email App</Subject>
    <Body><![CDATA[<h1>Testing Email Data</h1><br/><hr /><br/><h6>Testing Email</h6></hr />]]></Body>
</EmailData>
```